# Call functions/variables/tables from a separate file in Lua

Tags: lua, love2d

I'm currently working on a fairly detailed project in Lua, specifically using LOVE2D.  I'm currently using `require'file'` in order to access different parts of my project, but this seems like very poor form.  I've ran into the problem of overwriting tables from different files with the same name.  There must be a professional, cleaner way to do this, but I haven't been able to find one.  Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you have two modules with the same name?  Or just two global tables with the same name?  Please give an example to clarify your question.

Answer (score 3):

Using `require` *is* the right way to do it.

Think of a module as a function that gets executed when it's loaded. It's return value is cached and returned on subsequent require calls. Just like you would use `local` variables to limit the scope in a function, you can do the same in a module.

I'm guessing your modules are implemented as global tables:

```
mymodule = {}

function mymodule.foo()
  return 'bar'
end
```

And you load the module like:

```
require 'mymodule'
```

Just change the module table to a `local` variable and return it:

```
local mymodule = {}

function mymodule.foo()
  return 'bar'
end

return mymodule
```

Then, you can load the module with any name you choose:

```
local mymodule = require 'mymodule'
```

Since you don't create global variables you don't have to worry about overwriting other modules.

The example used above is from the [Module Tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ModulesTutorial) on the lua-users.org website. Check it out for more info about creating modules. Also, [How to write Lua modules in a post-module() world](http://hisham.hm/2014/01/02/how-to-write-lua-modules-in-a-post-module-world/) is also worth reading.